# SharePoint 2010 & opening .mht files & 'x-usc'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, office-integration, office-web-apps, office

Whenever I open a .mht file from SharePoint(2010) I get the following security warning:
[image: Werid x-usc issue]

I notice that the .mht file that multiple images and as a result multiple security warning messages appear for each image. I think might identified the issue to be with the werid text that is highlighted in yellow: x-usc. From my research I've found that the text refers to spam technique that a outlook adds in urls to prevent end users to opening links from an email????I'm not really sure.
Any ideas????

Comment: It doesn't seem like the pictures are embedded, and it's trying to reference the picture in the webpage. Try a .mht without any pictures...post your results

Comment: The image references listed in the document pull from a folder on the C drive. Which at first you will that's the source, but this was working 2 months ago.